# How to keep my react native app agora call keep going on even in background?

Tags: react-native, agora

I am developing a video call app using Agora. I have implemented the functions and the app is working. But I have also a file attachment function to select file and send over chat. But when file is opened agora gets disconnected. To know what happened I tried going home screen in phone and agora call gets disconnected. So the call is not running in background. How can I make that happen. Keep call until the app is killed.